# ruby on rails - Unique multiple key index issue in production (Heroku PostgreSQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, indexing, key

I am facing an issue I have tried to solve by myself but I don't get what's wrong. I am French so my models, controllers... have french names.

I am developing an app for an association that makes what we call in French "maraudes" every night : driving around to meet people.

I have this Maraude model :

```
class Maraude < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope -> { order(date: :desc) }
  validates :date,  presence: true,
                    uniqueness: { scope: :type_maraude }
  validates :type_maraude, presence: true
end
```

My maraudes have `:date` and `:type_maraude` attributes, and I want them to define every maraude, so that every maraude has a unique `[:date, :type_maraude]` combination.

In order to do this, I also created this migration :

```
class AddIndexToMaraudes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :maraudes, [:date, :type_maraude], unique: true
  end
end
```

It is perfectly working in development. In production (Heroku), I have created a maraude dated 2016-02-02 with a certain type (Maraude salariés 1) and when trying to create an other maraude at the same date but with a different type I get the following error and I don't understand where it may come from :

```
2016-02-05T13:56:51.810031+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/maraudes" for 80.13.244.250 at 2016-02-05 13:56:51 +0000
2016-02-05T13:56:51.823195+00:00 app[web.1]:   Maraude Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "maraudes" WHERE ("maraudes"."date" = '2016-02-02' AND "maraudes"."type_maraude" = 'Maraude bénévoles') LIMIT 1
2016-02-05T13:56:51.812447+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MaraudesController#create as HTML
2016-02-05T13:56:51.829572+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 5.9ms)
2016-02-05T13:56:51.819326+00:00 app[web.1]:   Maraude Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "maraudes".* FROM "maraudes" WHERE "maraudes"."date" = $1 AND "maraudes"."type_maraude" = $2  ORDER BY "maraudes"."date" DESC LIMIT 1  [["date", "2016-02-02"], ["type_maraude", "Maraude bénévoles"]]
2016-02-05T13:56:51.812533+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"useo/o+NPJ6cemrRfdUN2LRIsDCAHiseYTlV2EKXigH/6C47ZzEhtM0mCra7EuY/QY/nZuXdpfnTDxR4VugUdw==", "maraude"=>{"date"=>"2016-02-02", "type_maraude"=>"Maraude bénévoles"}, "commit"=>"Créer la maraude"}
2016-02-05T13:56:51.828110+00:00 app[web.1]: DETAIL:  Key (date)=(2016-02-02) already exists.
2016-02-05T13:56:51.814745+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-02-05T13:56:51.820512+00:00 app[web.1]:    (0.7ms)  BEGIN
2016-02-05T13:56:51.828073+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "maraudes" ("date", "type_maraude", "villes", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["date", "2016-02-02"], ["type_maraude", "Maraude bénévoles"], ["villes", ""], ["created_at", "2016-02-05 13:56:51.823377"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-05 13:56:51.823377"]]
2016-02-05T13:56:51.828108+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_maraudes_on_date"
2016-02-05T13:56:51.828111+00:00 app[web.1]: : INSERT INTO "maraudes" ("date", "type_maraude", "villes", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"
2016-02-05T13:56:51.829215+00:00 app[web.1]:    (0.9ms)  ROLLBACK
2016-02-05T13:56:51.832064+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-02-05T13:56:51.832067+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_maraudes_on_date"
2016-02-05T13:56:51.832068+00:00 app[web.1]: DETAIL:  Key (date)=(2016-02-02) already exists.
2016-02-05T13:56:51.832069+00:00 app[web.1]: : INSERT INTO "maraudes" ("date", "type_maraude", "villes", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"):
2016-02-05T13:56:51.832070+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/maraudes_controller.rb:34:in `create'
```

The PG error seems to indicate that it behaves like I had created a unique index on `:date` which is not the case...

For info here is my 'create' action in my Maraudes controller.
EDIT : I translated the flash messages.

```
def create
  @maraude = Maraude.new(maraude_params)
  @maraude.villes = ""
  if Maraude.find_by(date: params[:maraude][:date], type_maraude: params[:maraude][:type_maraude])
    flash[:danger] = "This maraude already exists"
    redirect_to new_maraude_path
  elsif @maraude.save
    flash[:success] = "Maraude created"
    redirect_to id_m_villes_path(id: @maraude.id)
  else  
    flash[:danger] = "Give date and maraude type"
    redirect_to new_maraude_path
  end
end
```

Thx for your help !

Comment: Hi Elie. I've not very well understand from where came from the problem, but, reading log is like your db index do not include "maraude_id", but only "date". If it was for me I would try to query directly database with console or some db manager on Heroku, to sure me of index configuration ... an try to insert data to verify if error really depends from db. Use you the same db on both environments ? Maybe do you need an add-on on Heroku ? Bonne travail :)

Comment: Thx for your answer ! The model does include the default id because I use it often. See in my create action : I created a route using the id of the maraude directing to a page where you can post the cities the maraude has been through, and no problem. I will try to find a db manager tomorrow, thx. Same db on both environments. I don't think I need an add-on, heroku is made to be as simple as possible and I have been searching an answer to my problem, no one talks about a gem or whatever supposed to solve this. Plus I use the same type of index on another model and no problem also !